# Laravel 5 Class 'app\Models\Colour' not found

Tags: php, class, oop, laravel, eloquent

Up into this morning my app was working great, I've created classes in `app/Models` with no issues. I added an eloquent class called `Colours` which contains the RGB values for named Colours for use in a lookup table however the code produces a fatal error about the class not existing.

The database is migrated and seeded correctly with no issues. However the following line of code is breaking my app

```
$c = Colour::query()->findOrFail(2);
```

Now why this troubles me is I have another class Wheel which is called earlier in the same class as follows

```
$wheel = Wheel::query()->findOrFail($data['settings']['wheel']);
```

This code runs and returns the data row as requested. Looking into other Class not found posts suggested a namespace issue, however both colours and wheel are in the same file location (`app\Models`) this is defined in the namespace tag. I've added the class as a use, added both of these as uses, I've created a model with artisan in `app/` I've tried

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Again no luck and class not found. I'm at a loss with this, I have other classes which call database queries in the same way on other tables which have no such issues, the content of my Wheel and Colour models are identical (except obviously the class name itself).

Additional I've just noticed that I'm within `Wheel.php` but unlike the main class used by my app the Wheel class is an eloquent object could this prevent me from getting the datarow of another table object? How can I resolve this? Will I in essence need to create another class with my methods in and keep my wheel class as just an eloquent class?

This model has no controller, not directly related to the wheel model. The action which calls this model from within a base controller is

```
public function wheel(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->session()->get('data');
    $model = new Wheel();
    $wheel = $model->drawWheel($data);
    return view('wheel', ['wheel' => $wheel]);
}
```

As said up until I wanted colour names this worked fine. The Model is

```
<?php

namespace app\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Wheel extends Model
{

    private function drawWheels($im, $data, $wheel)
    {
        $m = 250;
        $r = $wheel['inner_r'];
        $spokes = $data['spokes'];
        $l = $data['format'];
        foreach ($spokes as $a) {
            $oA = cos(deg2rad($l[$a['A']]));
            $aA = sin(deg2rad($l[$a['A']]));
            $xA = $m - ($r * $oA);
            $yA = $m - ($r * $aA);
            $oB = cos(deg2rad($l[$a['B']]));
            $aB = sin(deg2rad($l[$a['B']]));
            $xB = $m - ($r * $oB);
            $yB = $m - ($r * $aB);

            $c = Colour::query()->findOrFail(2);
            //$c = Colour::where('name', '=', strtolower($a['name']))->first();
            //$c = DB::table('colours')->where('name', strtolower($a['name']))->first();

            $color = imagecolorallocate($im, $c['R'], $c['G'], $c['B']);

            imageline($im, $xA, $yA, $xB, $yB, $color);
        }

        return $im;
    }

}
```

Here is my app/Models/Colour class

```
<?php

namespace app\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Colour extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

P.S the drawWheel function referred to in the base controller just calls the private function drawWheels (well ok it does other calls but these work and i can step through the code with xdebug and it works until it tries to load the colour row from the database)

The full error i get is

```
FatalErrorException in Wheel.php line 64: Class 'app\Models\Colour' not found

in Wheel.php line 64
at FatalErrorException->__construct('message' => '', 'code' => '', 'severity' => '', 'filename' => '', 'lineno' => '', 'traceOffset' => '', 'traceArgs' => '', 'trace' => '') in HandleExceptions.php line 133
at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError('error' => '', 'traceOffset' => '') in HandleExceptions.php line 118
at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown() in HandleExceptions.php line 0
at Wheel->drawAspects('im' => '', 'data' => '', 'wheel' => '') in Wheel.php line 30
at Wheel->drawHoroscope('data' => '') in ChartController.php line 33
at ChartController->wheel('request' => '') in Controller.php line 256
at call_user_func_array('', '') in Controller.php line 256
at Controller->callAction('method' => '', 'parameters' => '') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 164
at ControllerDispatcher->call('instance' => '', 'route' => '', 'method' => '') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 112
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}('request' => '') in Pipeline.php line 139
at call_user_func('', '') in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}('passable' => '') in Pipeline.php line 103
at call_user_func('', '') in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then('destination' => '') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 114
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack('instance' => '', 'route' => '', 'request' => '', 'method' => '') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 69
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch('route' => '', 'request' => '', 'controller' => '', 'method' => '') in Route.php line 203
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher('request' => '') in Route.php line 134
at Route->run('request' => '') in Router.php line 712
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}('request' => '') in Pipeline.php line 139
at call_user_func('', '') in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}('passable' => '') in Pipeline.php line 103
at call_user_func('', '') in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then('destination' => '') in Router.php line 714
at Router->runRouteWithinStack('route' => '', 'request' => '') in Router.php line 679
at Router->dispatchToRoute('request' => '') in Router.php line 639
at Router->dispatch('request' => '') in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}('request' => '') in Pipeline.php line 139
at call_user_func('', '') in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}('passable' => '') in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle('request' => '', 'next' => '') in Pipeline.php line 124
at call_user_func_array('', '') in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}('passable' => '') in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle('request' => '', 'next' => '') in Pipeline.php line 124
at call_user_func_array('', '') in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}('passable' => '') in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle('request' => '', 'next' => '') in Pipeline.php line 124
at call_user_func_array('', '') in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}('passable' => '') in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle('request' => '', 'next' => '') in Pipeline.php line 124
at call_user_func_array('', '') in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}('passable' => '') in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle('request' => '', 'next' => '') in Pipeline.php line 124
at call_user_func_array('', '') in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}('passable' => '') in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle('request' => '', 'next' => '') in Pipeline.php line 124
at call_user_func_array('', '') in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}('passable' => '') in Pipeline.php line 103
at call_user_func('', '') in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then('destination' => '') in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter('request' => '') in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle('request' => '') in index.php line 54
at {main}() in index.php line 0
```

The line in Wheel at line 64 is the

```
$c = Colour::query()->findOrFail(2);
```

My composer.json autoload section (and the dev one) is

```
    "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
```

Comment: Can you show your model and controller? (relative parts)

Comment: Without seeing your folder structure, autoloading scheme and imported classes it is really hard to say what's wrong.

Comment: make sure you had `use app\Models\Colour` in your controller

Comment: @Daan updated post with relevant controller and model details. Tezla I've tried that but in other models in the app i dont use the full class and it works, adding it doesnt work.  vikingmaster all my model classes are in App/Models for simplicity as I'm still learning laravel. auto loaders well isnt that done automatically? not sure on imported classes, how would i know what they are? As i said in initial post i have another model which loads several other models and this has no issues at all. Only this one i added today.

Comment: @Tezla, adding the app/Models/Colour Class to the base controller didn't work

Comment: maybe something is wrong in the Colour file class? Try to post it as well

Comment: @Moppo added colour class to op

Comment: just noticed that the colour class is not in the composer autoload-classmap file. I added it manually and then ran composer and it removed it so it isnt being found right? how can i make it found?

Comment: app\Models\Color should be located in app\Models folder.
No dum-autoload is required.

Comment: you can also try to post the full error message you get, as long with the stack trace...maybe that could help

Comment: @Yauheni Prakopchyk the Colour.php file is in app\Models folder

Comment: @moppo added full error with stack trace

Comment: @Craig Stanfield this is strange. Mind sharing your composer.json autoload section?

Comment: Are you using dependency injection? Can you add the code where you're doing that. Along with that add \app\Models\Colour, see if that works.

Comment: i see from the trace the method calls : `Wheel->drawAspects`, `Wheel->drawHoroscope`. Are they suggesting something strange to you ? As i don't see them in the code

Comment: @Guarav Dave No dependency injection is being used at this point as project is relatively simple.

Comment: @Moppo no those methods work and are called before this point, i didn't include as felt as working code they werent relevent. i mean it is just returning the id of the second row in the table with the code i used (although up until this error it references the actual name not the id as in the test i setup) all data is correct, the calculations are correct, the colour name generated (but not used in this test) is correct and exists. everything about the code is working fine, if i just create a gd colour and use this and dont call colour model it works (but doesn't change the colour obviously)

Comment: @Yauheni Prakopchyk updated op to include composer.json autoload sections

Comment: Has the Model itself PSR-4 standards? http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/ Is the file Colour.php first letter uppercase?

Comment: @Craig Stanfield got the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Namespaces for models should be `App\Models`, not `app\Models`.

You may check [composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) on PSR-4 autoload.

Comment: Ahh you sir are a genious. Noticed i used app/Models in 2 locations. Once corrected issue vanished

Comment: No problems. You may accept the answer if it fits the bill.

Comment: @Moppo Maybe it was loaded without autoloader: `require('class_file.php')`.